# Missing OSM Points after importing osm.pbf into PostGIS DB

Tags: openstreetmap, geocoding, osm2pgsql, nominatim

Can you tell me how to import OSM data into PostGIS database without lose any data?

I am using map extracts from https://mapzen.com . At first I download Raw OpenStreetMap datasets in PBF, but after importing it by osm2pgsql, I do not have all points. For example when some street have numbers from 1 to 20, its 20 points, but after import I have only 4. But when I download Datasets split by geometry type: lines, points, or polygons (SHP) and import pure shp file into PostGIS, I have all points with that street (1 - 20).

I need this data for 2 things.

1. geocoding - i need compare text value of point (city, street, street number) with user entered text values in routing
2. generate base map and style it in geoserver

Is possible set up this tool to import all points?

Or is some other way for windows?

Comment: Can you name a specific node by ID that is missing from your database?

Comment: Maybe your osm2pgsql is outdated and does not support 64bit node ids?